# How to prevent xfce from increasing the sound level when playing a warning sound?

Tags: audio, xfce, alsa, settings, alsamixer

Consider following case

> I am listening to music on `xfce 4.12`. The sound level is on 25% of the maximum in `ALSA Mixer`. Suddenly, an application [I reproduced it using two different applications] gives a loud warning sound. I open `ALSA Mixer`, and it seems that the sound level has automatically been set to 100%.
>
> After this incident, I manually put the sound level on 25%, but cannot hear the music anymore. If I set it to 100%, I hear a sound level that corresponds to what used to be 25% before the incident.

What did happen? Is it possible to prevent this from happening again (in order to save your ears)?

**Details**

- The installed ALSA version is `k4.9.0-5-amd64` ([see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394846/how-can-i-get-the-installed-alsa-version)).
- This happened for instance while listening to music on 25%. I downloaded a file and opened it in Okular. The sound level was set to 100% and a warning (with sound) told me that Okular could not open the file.
- It happened again in Konqueror when it opened an error

> Security Information - Konqueror
>
> You are about to leave secure mode. Transmissions will no longer be
>   encrypted.
>
> This means that a third party could observe your data in transit."

- Sound was again changed from about 25% to 100% when `Kate` mentioned a warning (on this computer with ALSA version `k4.9.0-11-amd64`).